# Force compiled CSS inline with Angular & Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin, extract-text-plugin

Is there a way I can get Webpack to add a compiled **SCSS → CSS** file to my Angular project's **index.html** head as an *inline* style tag?

The goal is to style the *"Loading ..."* page displayed while Angular is busy bootstrapping. In order to avoid FOUC the resulting CSS file needs to be injected inline, as a style tag in my index.html's head. This way, once index.html is loaded, we don't need to wait for another network resource to load in order to see our pre-bootstrap styling.

This might also be a worthy approach to inline a small logo inside the index.html page as a base64 data URI.

The project was created with Angular CLI and uses Angular 4 with Webpack 2.  I ejected the Webpack configuration with `ng eject` and made minor modifications to *webpack.config.js*. I pretty much only removed LESS and Stylus support from the configuration.

Here's my webpack.config.js for reference:

```
const path = require('path');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');

const {NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin, LoaderOptionsPlugin} = require('webpack');
const {GlobCopyWebpackPlugin, BaseHrefWebpackPlugin} = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
const {CommonsChunkPlugin} = require('webpack').optimize;
const {AotPlugin} = require('@ngtools/webpack');

const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
const entryPoints = ["inline", "polyfills", "sw-register", "styles", "twbs", "vendor", "main"];
const baseHref = "";
const deployUrl = "";

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    devServer: {
        port: 4200,
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            ".ts",
            ".js"
        ],
        modules: [
            "./node_modules"
        ]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: [
            "./node_modules"
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        main: [
            "./src/main.ts"
        ],
        polyfills: [
            "./src/polyfills.ts"
        ],
        styles: [
            "./src/styles/styles.scss",
            "./src/styles/vendor.scss"
        ],
        twbs: 'bootstrap-loader'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader",
                exclude: [
                    /node_modules/
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "raw-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg)$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani)$/,
                loader: "url-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]&limit=10000"
            },
            {
                exclude: [
                    path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/styles.scss"),
                    path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/vendor.scss")
                ],
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
                    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
                    "postcss-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                exclude: [
                    path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/styles.scss"),
                    path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/vendor.scss")
                ],
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: [
                    "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
                    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
                    "postcss-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                include: [
                    path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/styles.scss"),
                    path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/vendor.scss")
                ],
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
                        "postcss-loader"
                    ],
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    publicPath: ""
                })
            },
            {
                include: [
                    path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/styles.scss"),
                    path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/vendor.scss")
                ],
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
                        "postcss-loader",
                        "sass-loader"
                    ],
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    publicPath: ""
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: "@ngtools/webpack"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            Tether: "tether",
            "window.Tether": "tether",
            Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
            Alert: "exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
            Button: "exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button",
            Carousel: "exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
            Collapse: "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
            Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
            Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
            Popover: "exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
            Scrollspy: "exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
            Tab: "exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
            Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util"
        }),
        new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                "assets",
                "favicon.ico"
            ],
            globOptions: {
                "cwd": "./src",
                "dot": true,
                "ignore": "**/.gitkeep"
            }
        }),
        new ProgressPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
            hash: false,
            inject: true,
            compile: true,
            favicon: false,
            minify: false,
            cache: true,
            showErrors: true,
            chunks: "all",
            excludeChunks: [],
            title: "Webpack App",
            xhtml: true,
            chunksSortMode: function sort(left, right) {
                let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
                let rightindex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
                if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }),
        new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "inline",
            minChunks: null
        }),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor",
            minChunks: (module) => module.resource && module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules),
            chunks: [
                "main"
            ]
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "[name].bundle.css",
            disable: true
        }),
        new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            sourceMap: false,
            options: {
                postcss: [
                    autoprefixer(),
                    postcssUrl({
                        url: (URL) => {
                            // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
                            if (!URL.startsWith('/') || URL.startsWith('//')) {
                                return URL;
                            }
                            if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//)) {
                                // If deployUrl contains a scheme, ignore baseHref use deployUrl as is.
                                return `${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${URL}`;
                            }
                            else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
                                // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
                                return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') +
                                    `/${deployUrl}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                            }
                            else {
                                // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
                                // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
                                return `/${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                            }
                        }
                    })
                ],
                sassLoader: {
                    sourceMap: false,
                    includePaths: []
                },
                context: ""
            }
        }),
        new AotPlugin({
            mainPath: "main.ts",
            hostReplacementPaths: {
                "environments/environment.ts": "environments/environment.ts"
            },
            exclude: [],
            tsConfigPath: "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            skipCodeGeneration: true
        })
    ],
    node: {
        fs: "empty",
        global: true,
        crypto: "empty",
        tls: "empty",
        net: "empty",
        process: true,
        module: false,
        clearImmediate: false,
        setImmediate: false
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm nudging closer to a solution by installing the html-webpack-inline-source-plugin, and just blindly setting inlineSource to '.' for now. I can see all my JS loading, so probably would need to create a separate bundle for the stuff I want to inline, and refine the regex on inlineSource to only inline that single file.

Comment: It seems what I am asking is to force a CSS file to fallback to style-loader, perhaps?

Comment: I think you're on the right path.

Comment: Have you considered using Angular Universal to have part of the page rendered on the server for fast "time-to-render" on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to resolve my puzzle by using a combination of the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) and [style-ext-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/style-ext-html-webpack-plugin) Let's assume a folder structure as follows:

```
|- src
   |- index.ejs
   |- inline.css
   |- main.css
   |- main.js
```

*main.js* contains the following:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import './inline.css';
import './main.css';

function component() {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'Webpack', '!!!'], ' ');
    return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

The aim is to have Webpack generate dist/index.html and render inline.css directly in the resulting head of index.html. Further main.css loads via the css-loader.

To achieve this, I created *webpack.config.js* as follows:

```
const path = require('path');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const StyleExtHtmlPlugin = require('style-ext-html-webpack-plugin');

const extractSplashCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('splash.css');
const extractMainCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                include: [
                    path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/inline.css')
                ],
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: extractSplashCSS.extract({
                    use: 'css-loader'
                })
            },
            {
                exclude: [
                    path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/inline.css')
                ],
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: extractMainCSS.extract({
                    use: 'css-loader'
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractSplashCSS,
        extractMainCSS,
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Hello Webpack 2',
            template: 'src/index.ejs',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new StyleExtHtmlPlugin('splash.css')
    ]
};
```

The resulting index.html contains inline.css embedded as a style tag in the head of index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Webpack 2</title>
<style>body {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}</style><link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
<p>Webpack 2...</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you made any specific change to your index.ejs template file in order for the css to be inlined?

Answer (score 1):

This was too much work, this is easier. It's the barest min you can do to do an animated spinner with no magic and extra plugins.

```
  <app-root>
  <style type="text/css">
    initial-loading-indicator {
      z-index: 1200;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      content: '';
      font-size: 10px;
      width: 1em;
      height: 1em;
      -ms-animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
      animation: spinner 1500ms infinite linear;
      border-radius: 0.5em;
      box-shadow: #495057 1.5em 0 0 0, #495057 1.1em 1.1em 0 0, #495057 0 1.5em 0 0, #495057 -1.1em 1.1em 0 0, #495057 -1.5em 0 0 0, #495057 -1.1em -1.1em 0 0, #495057 0 -1.5em 0 0, #495057 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;
    }

    @keyframes spinner {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
<initial-loading-indicator></initial-loading-indicator>
  </app-root>
```